# sbt and multiple unmanaged lib directories

Tags: sbt

I have two directories containing jars:

- lib-a
- lib-b

I want to include all jars in the lib-a directory and a specified set of jars from the lib-b directory. How can I configure this using sbt (I'm using v0.12.2).

I've tried editing unmanaged-base, but that only allow one to specify one directory. I think the key is unmanaged-jars, which is a task. I'm new to sbt, though, and don't know how to configure this.